# Init Eclipse Che pulling images from a Nexus group repository to docker hub

Tags: nexus3, eclipse-che

I'm trying to deploy a Eclipse Che multiuser server using Docker Enterprise Edition 2.0.

The Docker EE server is NOT exposed to internet and Docker Hub access is proxed by a Nexus Repository server (nexq.xxxx.it).

I'm looking for a -e parameter to configure but -e CHE_DOCKER_REGISTRY seems used only for workspace creation but not for Eclipse Che init images pull.

Here the command I'm using:

```
docker run -it --rm -e CHE_MULTIUSER=true -e CHE_HOST=yyyy.xxxx.it -e CHE_DOCKER_REGISTRY=nexq.xxxx.it -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v /root/eedata:/data nexq.xxxx.it/eclipse/che:6.6.0 start --fast
```

Here the cli.log log:

```
[root@orme eedata]# tail -f cli.log
eval IMAGE_CHE=${IMAGE_CHE:-eclipse/che-server:6.6.0}
eval IMAGE_COMPOSE=${IMAGE_COMPOSE:-docker/compose:1.10.1}
eval IMAGE_POSTGRES=${IMAGE_POSTGRES:-centos/postgresql-96-centos7:9.6}
eval IMAGE_KEYCLOACK=${IMAGE_KEYCLOACK:-jboss/keycloak-openshift:3.3.0.CR2-3}
eval UTILITY_IMAGE_CHEACTION=${UTILITY_IMAGE_CHEACTION:-eclipse/che-action:6.6.0}
eval UTILITY_IMAGE_CHEDIR=${UTILITY_IMAGE_CHEDIR:-eclipse/che-dir:6.6.0}
eval UTILITY_IMAGE_CHETEST=${UTILITY_IMAGE_CHETEST:-eclipse/che-test:6.6.0}
eval UTILITY_IMAGE_CHEMOUNT=${UTILITY_IMAGE_CHEMOUNT:-eclipse/che-mount:6.6.0}
INFO: (che cli):  Pulling image alpine:3.4
docker pull alpine:3.4 >> "/data/cli.log" 2>&1
ERROR: Image alpine:3.4 unavailable. Not on dockerhub or built locally.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use form:
`registry.address:port/image`, e.g. in your case:
`nexq.xxxx.it/alpine:3.4`